Run GraphQL query in ADF dataflow
I am trying to create an ADF dataflow to extract data from API using GraphQL query. It has nested structures, and I believe copy activity does not support nested structures.
I tried using dataflow, but I receive errors.
Here is the query I am trying to pass from Rest body:
{
  "query": `
    query($startTime: Long!, $endTime: Long!) {
      agentSession(from: $startTime, to: $endTime, pagination: { cursor: "0" }) {
        agentSessions {
          agentId
          teamId
          siteId
          channelInfo {
            channelId
            channelType
            totalDuration
            connectedDuration
            activities {
              nodes {
                id
                startTime
                endTime
              }
            }
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  "variables": {
    "startTime": 1704088615000,
    "endTime": 1719813415000
  }
}




Hi Suresh K, Could you provide what error you are getting ?

error screenshot added above

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
